# Remove the first step (i.e.login step) from the checkout process in a particular theme

Tags: magento-1.7, checkout, onestepcheckout

I have two themes (mobile and desktop) for the single store view.
 In mobile theme I want to remove the Login step which is the first step of the checkout process.
So now I have created a block with the following code (Thanks to @Abdul)

```
<?php 
class Remove_Step_Block_Checkout_Onepage extends Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage
{ 
  public function getSteps() 
  { 
    $steps = parent::getSteps(); 
    if (array_key_exists('login', $steps) && $this->checkMobileAgents()) { 
      unset($steps['login']); 
    } 
    return $steps; 
  } 

  public function getActiveStep() 
  { 
    return 'billing'; 
  } 

  public function checkMobileAgents() 
  { 
    $mobileAgents = "/(nokia|iphone|android|motorola|^mot\-|softbank|foma|docomo|kddi|up\.browser|up\.link|" 
.     "htc|dopod|blazer|netfront|helio|hosin|huawei|novarra|CoolPad|webos|techfaith|palmsource|" 
. "blackberry|blackberry10|bb10|playbook|alcatel|amoi|ktouch|nexian|samsung|^sam\-|s[cg]h|^lge|ericsson|philips|sagem|wellcom|bunjalloo|maui|" 
. "symbian|smartphone|mmp|midp|wap|phone|windows ce|iemobile|^spice|^bird|^zte\-|longcos|pantech|gionee|^sie\-|portalmmm|" 
. "jig\s browser|hiptop|^ucweb|^benq|haier|^lct|opera\s*mobi|opera\*mini|320x320|240x320|176x220" 
. ")/i"; 
  if (preg_match($mobileAgents, strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']))) { 
    return true;  
  } 
  return false; 
  } 
} 
?>
```

Now the problem is that in the checkout page the 2nd step is coming but in inactive state.
Please suggest how to make it active ?
Thank you.

Comment: Suppose i have added two products in cart without login after process checkout in this case customer must be login on login step. If customer already login and process checkout in this case default magento login step already hided.

Comment: @Abdul actually I am asked to do the "login" step previously. i.e. From cart page I am redirecting to another page as "login step"(i.e. login or checkout as guest) . Then some shipping methods and payment methods are calculated in the subsequent pages. Then comes the checkout page..And here I want to remove the login step which has already been done previously..

Comment: can pls share screen shot with eg.

Comment: @Abdul I have yet to implement it. so don't have screen shot..sorry..anything else can I provide ?

Comment: Is it possible to override the core checkout class to achieve this?

Comment: yes it is possible

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34390/discussion-between-kishore-patra-and-abdul).